# How to run two different versions of laravel side by side with different php versions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

I have a Laravel 7 project running on my PC with PHP version 7.2.5 installed. I want to run another project of Laravel 8 with PHP version>=7.3 required. What can I do? I want to run both projects on my PC at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: Generally it is not possible to run 2 versions at the same time. But you can dockerize your projects and have each container run with the respective PHP version.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail

Comment: I think so Laravel 7 is not supported for sail?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Docker for it. You can create 2 different docker container, 1 with PHP 7 and one with PHP 8

Or if you are using WAMP or other kind of stack there should be some part to change the PHP version

[image]

However, I suggest you to use docker. Laravel 9 comes with sail (I guess older versions too) you can simply install docker desktop and run

```
sail up
```

inside your project folder but if you check sail package you will see

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
```

It requires at least PHP 7.3

Comment: But is not supported for laravel 7. I'm using xampp.

Comment: I installed two xampps, one with php version 7.2.5 which is working fine for laravel 7 project and other one is with PHP version 8.0. I changed ports for apache and MySQL for second xampp and in phpinfo.php it is giving 8.0 but when I try to run command `composer install` , it gives me error that your php version is 7.2.5(Detecting old php version). I thought it will work but not!:(

Comment: No you should not install 2 xampss. You should install 1 xampp and 2 PHP versions. I guess you better use Docker. Laravel Sail is just a wrapper for docker. You can use docker-compose.yml file and other dependencies from sail. Actually now that I'm thinking you can use sail for your Laravel 9 and xampp for your Laravel 7

Comment: Package laravel/sail has requirements incompatible with your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version:
    - laravel/sail v1.13.5 requires php ^7.3|^8.0 which does not match your installed version 7.2.5.

Comment: This is error so if I change the PHP version 7.2.5 and upgrade it, my laravel 7 running project will not run

Comment: Yeah I said it in my answer Laravel Sail requires at least php 7.3. You do not need to use sail for your Laravel 7, and you can not. You should use your wamp on your old Laravel 7 project, and sail for your Laravel 8 project. Change your WAMP PHP version to old one serve your Laravel 7 project from there and just use sail up command for your Laravel 8 project.

Comment: You are right. I tried to run the `sail up` command after navigating to my laravel 8 project directory but it said that sail is not recognized as internal or external command.(Which means I've to install sail first). I run `composer require laravel/sail --dev` but it give the same error(PHP version )